# AppMaker table missing rows

Tags: google-app-maker, google-workspace

I created a non-paginated table from my datasource, but there are rows missing.

For example, say I have rows 1 to 200, I scroll the table all the way to the bottom and it shows me rows 1 to 150.
If I click the Coloumn Header to sort them descending, then it shows me rows 200 to 50.

Comment: What is your datasource page size?

Comment: BAM! Saved my life. Thank you so much!

Just a short description for those as new as I am to this:

Choose Datasource > Datasource tab > Query page size